# Реализация хостинга WCF в консольном приложении С#

Tags: c#, wcf, консоль

День добрый!

В принципе-то, не сложный вопрос, но запутался что-то.
Итак, в **отдельном проекте** есть некий WCF-сервис, объявленный в виде интерфейса `IMyWCF`:

```
namespace WCF_Service
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyWCF
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool TestConnection();
    }
}
```

А так же в отдельном файлике в проекте есть реализация оного интерфейса:

```
namespace WCF_Service
{
    public class MyWCF : IMyWCF
    {
        private string msg = string.Empty;

        // Конструктор
        public UpdaterService()
        {
            string msg = "Hello, WCF!";
            MessageBox.Show("Created\n"+msg);
        }

        public bool TestConnection()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

В VS сервис запускается, отрабатывает при помощи тестового клиента студии, всё хорошо.

Теперь нужно захостить сервис, и я пытаюсь сделать это на базе консольного приложения, которое создаю **в другом новом проекте**, в `usings` добавил `using System.ServiceModel;`, и тут началось самое интересное:

1. Дабы консольное приложение "знало" о сервисе (он ведь у нас в другом проекте), добавляю **Add... -> Service Reference...** где студия мне показывает адрес вида
   `http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WCF_Service/Service1/mex`, говорит, что найден 1 сервис, и внутри сервиса виден лишь интерфейс `IMyWCF`, сам класс `MyWCF` не доступен в качестве сервиса.
   Namespace в диалоговом окне добавления ссылки на сервис указываю как `WCF_ServiceHosting`.
2. После добавления ссылки на сервис я пытаюсь в программе выполнить следующий код:

   ```
   namespace WCF_ServiceHost
   {
       class Program
       {
           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               ServiceHost Host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WCF_ServiceHosting.IMyWCF));

               Host.Open();

               Console.ReadKey();

               Host.Close();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Разумеется, он валится при попытке создать новый сервис-хост из интерфейса `IMyWCF`, но беда в том, что самого класса `MyWCF`с реализацией этого интерфейса программа не видит.

**Большая просьба подсказть, как это победить и захостить WCF-службу в консольном приложении.**

Разумеется, гуглил, смотрел примеры,  в т.ч. на MSDN пример с калькулятором, и не только, но нигде нет таких проблем, следовательно, я делаю что-то не так, вопрос - что?

UPD. Сервис реализован в виде отдельной DLL, через шаблон WCF Service Library.

Comment: Зачем вы добавляете Service Reference на себя же самого?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, может, неудачно выразился, но ссылку на службу добавляю из проекта консольного приложения грубо говоря, на проект, в котором служба.

Comment: Так и добавляйте ссылку на проект. Зачем вы делаете ссылку на службу-то?

Comment: Ссылка на службу - это автогенерированный **клиент** службы. Вы не можете захостить клиента :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да вы, правы, конечно. Говорю же, запутался. Добавил ссылку на файлы библиотеки, все заработало, создался "сервер" службы и пошла другая ошибка "Служба "WCF_Service" не имеет конечных точек приложения (не инфраструктурных). Это может быть связано с тем, что для данного приложения не найден файл конфигурации", что логично, так как конфига пока еще нет. Но это уже другая задача.
Спасибо огромное! Оформляйте ответ ))

Comment: у меня точно такая же проблема..